# I can not consume a Rest API from my website using ajax where the port of API and Website are different

Tags: php, api

I have a Rest API developed in spring boot.It is running on port 9090.I have to consume the api from my website to get some data using angluarjs.The website is hosted in a shared hosting server which port is 80.Now there occurs problem  in consuming the API from 80 port to a different port 9090.

I also tried using curl from php there is same issue occurs.

Here is my API : https://****url****:9090/aubwebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/document/alldocuments

AngularJs Controller is :

```
$scope.getDocuments = function(){
                var search  = {
                    pageNo : 1,
                    studentId:"",
                    studentName:"",
                    rowPerPage:11
                };
                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: 'http://****url****:9090/aubwebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/document/alldocuments',
                    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(search),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data.documentList);
                    if(response.data.documentList === undefined || response.data.documentList.length == 0){
                        $scope.documents = [];
                    }else {
                        $scope.documents = response.data.documentList;
                        $scope.quantity = response.data.itemQuantity;
                    }
                    console.log($scope.documents,'All documents List');
                    console.log(response.data);
                });
            }
```

From the above call there is no api call take place.

How to consume an API from website whereas the port of the API and website deployed are different?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, known as CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

At its simplest, implement something like the following as a response to OPTIONS request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-origin-website
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

However, you claim you have the same issue when using curl from PHP. That shouldn't happen.

Some further discussion on this site related to CORS:

- [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?rq=1)
- [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Comment: Another important note that my api server does not provide a secure connection i.e it is accessed with http://. I also used http in my ajax call for the api url.But in networks it seems that it is calling with https://.Website server provides secure connection.please find the following snapshot : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uTFu8HwftSmM-EJ7QK96XGxy5RIXfOAa. so how to call with http instead of https from a secured server.